# What caulk color is this?

Tags: caulking, caulk

can anybody tell me what’s the color if the caulk used here? i replace the other side of my kitchen with silicone white and the colour is totally different with what is attached as picture.[image]

Comment: Is it translucent? Can you see through it some?  It may be clear that has opaqued over time.

Comment: on my computer mnitor It seems to be a 70% gray with a very slight yellow tint. did you perform a white balance before taking photo.

Comment: Sadly, _nobody_ on the internet is going to be able to tell because there's _no_ telling what kind of color balance your camera (phone, most likely) used, and because very few of our monitors are going to be color calibrated properly. If you took the shot in RAW mode and posted on [photography.se], someone there might be able to tell you, but it's likely off-topic for them, too. Also, odds are good that you're not going to find an exact match - all colors will fade or change over time. If you want an exact match, recaulk the entire area in question.

Comment: it could be white ... what color is the lighing?

Answer (score 1):

Matching something like this isn't possible, given the range of color reproduction on our computers. Vendors make samplers of their grout/ color match caulk; that would be the easiest way to roughly match. Alternately, buy a bunch of different color matched caulk from somewhere that will let you return the ones you don't need. Hopefully, the representation on the label will help you choose.

Comment: Yes, no way to tell the color. it could have been a color match when the counter was installed. Maybe cut off a small piece of the grey and bring it with to the store+1

Comment: It's funny/interesting that @JACK called it grey... I thought of it as linen.

Comment: I only have 10 colors in my crayon box.. lol

Comment: ...and there's always age to add to the issue. The same color caulking may not be the same color in a few years, and (if so)  new caulk of that color won't match it.